# how fix argon2i error in Sylius installation?

Tags: sylius

At the end of the installation with composer this error appears:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In SecurityExtension.php line 561:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Algorithm "argon2i" is not available. Either use "argon2id", "auto" or upgr  
!!    ade to PHP 7.2+ instead.                                                     
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

I use a Mac with Catalina OS

XAMPP

PHP 7.2.29

How can i fix this error

Comment: same using php 7.3.29

Answer (score 1):

Try to change in `config/packages/security.yaml` these lines:

```
security:
    ...
    encoders:
        Sylius\Component\User\Model\UserInterface:
            algorithm: sha512
        argon2i  : sha512
```

[source](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/10403#issuecomment-581356896)